# Could the below method of creating a dropdown menu using AngularJS be done a different way?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to integrate AngularJS into a website I'm experimenting with. In the original code, I had a few elements that were duplicated so I am using AngularJS to remedy this. The code is as follows:

```
<nav id=global>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Blog</a></li>
      <li id=projects>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>
        <ul id=dropdown-toggle>
          <li><a href=html/omnicode.html>Project1</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Project2</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Project3</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Project4</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Project5</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Project6</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Project7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>            
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>            
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I used the following code to remove the duplication:

```
<nav id=global ng-controller="NavListCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="nav in navheaders" ng-switch on="isProjects(nav)">                            
        <a href={{nav.link}}>{{nav.name}}</a>
        <ul id=dropdown-toggle ng-switch-when="true">
          <script>var el = this.parent(); el.id = "projects"</script>
          <li ng-repeat="proj in projects">
            <a href={{proj.link}}>{{proj.name}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>            
      </li>               
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Just in case, here is the contents of my controller.js file:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

function NavListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.navheaders = [
        {"name": "Home", 
         "link": "index.html"},
        {"name": "Blog",
         "link": "#"},
        {"name": "Projects",
         "link": "#"},
        {"name": "About",
         "link": "#"},
        {"name": "Contact",
         "link": "#"}
];

$scope.isProjects = function (nav) {
    return nav.name == "Projects";
}

$scope.projects = [
    {"name": "Project1",
     "link": "html/omnicode.html"},
    {"name": "Project2",
     "link": "#"},
    {"name": "Project3",
     "link": "#"},
    {"name": "Project4",
     "link": "#"},
    {"name": "Project5",
     "link": "#"},
    {"name": "Project6",
     "link": "#"},
    {"name": "Project7",
     "link": "#"}
  ];
```

}

Is there a better way to carry out this operation? Also, I am not sure how to insert "id=projects" into the li element that contains "Projects". My code:

```
<script>var el = this.parent(); el.id = "projects"</script>
```

was a feeble attempt at doing such. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to put "projects" into Id? You really dont need IDs with AngularJS unless you are using it for css or unless you are modifying the dom elements that need ID to reference it.

Comment: Yes I'm using id for css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend your model with an id property:

```
$scope.navheaders = [
    {"name": "Home", 
     "link": "index.html"},
    {"name": "Blog",
     "link": "#"},
    {"name": "Projects",
     "link": "#",
     "id": "projects" },
    {"name": "About",
     "link": "#"},
    {"name": "Contact",
     "link": "#"}
```

### ];

```
<li ng-repeat="nav in navheaders" ng-switch on="isProjects(nav)" id="{{nav.id}}"> ...</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Such a simple solution, I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it before.